# Having trouble with HTML/php forum image upload

Tags: php, html, forms

**Preface:**

I would like to state that I have no experience with PHP. I've been making edits to the PHP file by simply using common sense.

**Problem:**

I've recently started working on a new website and I'm coding this one 100% from scratch. But I want to add a image submission forum and so I looked around the web for a little bit and from visiting multiple different websites I was able to come up with the following php code (which I have tested and it works)[This php code is in a `LevelBRSubmit.php` file]:

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "example@email.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$yourname = check_input($_POST['yourname'], "Enter your Username");
$email    = check_input($_POST['email'] "Provide your Email");
$comments = check_input($_POST['comments'], "Write your comments");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
    show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Hello!

Your contact form has been submitted by:

Username: $yourname
E-mail: $email

Level Description:
$comments

End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, 'New Level Submition!', $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: http://projectskyforums.x10.mx/');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
    <html>
    <body>

    <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    <input type="button" value="Back To Forum" />

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Along with this forum (which is in an `BaseHTMLPlate.html` file):

```
    <div class="textBox">
<p>Required fields are <b>bold</b></p>

<form action="LevelBRSubmit.php" method="post">
<p><b>Your Username:</b> <input type="text" name="yourname" /><br />
<b>E-mail:</b> <input type="text" name="email" /><br />

<p><b>Your comments:</b><br />
<textarea name="comments" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Send it!"></p>
</div>
```

When I added the image upload button it all stopped working (which I already assumed would happen):

```
<div class="textBox">
<p>Required fields are <b>bold</b></p>

<form action="LevelBRSubmit.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p><b>Your Username:</b> <input type="text" name="yourname" /><br />
<b>E-mail:</b> <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
<b>Your Level Design:</b><input type="file" value="Upload Image" name="pic" accept="image/*"><br />

<p><b>Your comments:</b><br />
<textarea name="comments" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Send it!"></p>
</div>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "example@email.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$yourname = check_input($_POST['yourname'], "Enter your Username");
$email    = check_input($_POST['email'] "Provide your Email");
$pic = $_FILES['pic']['name'];
$comments = check_input($_POST['comments'], "Write your comments");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
    show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Hello!

Your contact form has been submitted by:

Username: $yourname
E-mail: $email

Level Description:
$comments

Level Design: $pic

End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, 'New Level Submition!', $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: http://projectskyforums.x10.mx/');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
    <html>
    <body>

    <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    <input type="button" value="Back To Forum" >

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

**Update**
The PHP sent the email! But instead of displaying the image the email simply displays the images name.

If anyone would like to give the page itself a look you can find it at the website link below (the website is still in early stages of development):
http://projectskyforums.x10.mx/BaseHTMLPlate.html

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php go through that, you're missing something in the form.

Comment: It's also unknown if you closed off your form or not.

Comment: enable error reporting and you'll see a few errors, believe me.

Comment: to upload a file, using a regular form submission, set the form attribute `enctype` to `multipart/form-data`

Comment: @RamRaider like this? <form action="LevelBRSubmit.php" method="POST" attribute="multipart/form-data">

Comment: @RamRaider that isn't the only thing wrong in there, look more closely. Ok... I'm out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag and to receive file in your php file you have to use `$_FILES['pic']` to get your file data.

```
<form action="LevelBRSubmit.php" method="post">
```

Replace above line with this

```
<form action="LevelBRSubmit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

In your **`LevelBRSubmit.php`** file change this line

```
$pic    = check_input($_POST['pic'] "Provide your Design");
```

to this

```
$pic = $_FILES['pic']['name'];
```

The new line give you the name of image file. You can find all data using `$_FILES['pic']` for your image file.

Comment: ok so the first error message is gone now I only have:
.........
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: do I just have to add a <DOCTYPE!> to the php file?

Comment: if you want to send image file in your mail() then you must have to add headers and image file using <img> tag in your message variable.

Set this headers

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

Comment: Level Design: ".<img src='PATH-TO-YOUR-UPLOADED-FILE'>."
this uploaded file must be in your web to access it in mail. if file is not in correct path then is will not be displayed in mail.